# Installing BeautifulSoup4 via pip produces an import error for Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip, python-2to3

I'm trying to install beautifulsoup4 for Python 3.5, however, I've made it to when I call 'import bs4' to test in the Python 3.5.2 shell, I receive the error below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import bs4
>     File "C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\bs4__init__.py", line 53
>       'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'
>                                                                                                          ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have followed the below path to run pip to originally install beatifulsoup4, the command I used to install around a company proxy was: $ pip install --proxy=proxy.com beautifulsoup4

> C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts

I had a previous installation of Python 2.7 on this computer, however I uninstalled it when I installed 3.5. If I did not uninstall Python 2.7 properly, could pip have failed to install and convert bs4 for 3.5? I've also attempted these same steps with the Requests module. I have tried to convert using the commands recommended by the Python shell, but my attempts to use '2to3' have failed as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does `pip --version` output?

Comment: The output is, `pip 8.1.1 from C:\...\python35\lib\site-packages (python 3.5)`

Comment: can you also add the output of `pip show bs4`?

Comment: The output suggested I upgrade from 8.1.1 to 9.0.1 with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. I upgraded to 9.0.1 and uninstalled bs4, then attempted to install again via the new version of pip. Still receiving the same error.

Comment: this is really strange that you have a python2 version of bs4 installed in a python3 path (`Python35` is part of the path..)

Comment: Would it be best to uninstall everything Python related I can find on my pc, and reinstall? Could it be a remnant of Python 2 stopping me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133664/discussion-between-hansaplast-and-danielson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow a python2 version of of `bs4` was installed into your python3 directory. In order to fix that you coult manually fix it by removing all bs4 files in `C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\` (the `bs4__init__.py` file and also the bs4 subdirectory)

If you now do a `pip install bs4` then `pip` thinks it has bs4 already installed so you need to do this:

```
pip install bs4 --ignore-installed
```